# Record number of unique values based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table of data of players who played for different teams over several weeks of different years/seasons.  What I'd like to do, is have the number of unique years a player (Typed in cell G1) has played on a team.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following formula:

```
=LET(x,(--(Table1[Player]=$G$1))*(--(Table1[Team]=F4)*(--(Table1[Year]))),COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(x,x>0),FALSE)))
```

Drag it down.

**Explanation:**

- `(--(Table1[Player]=$G$1))*(--(Table1[Team]=F4)*(--(Table1[Year])))`: finds rows where the player is listed in combination with the team. If not found, `0` is listed in for .
- `FILTER(x,x>0)`: filters non zero rows.
- `UNIQUE(FILTER(x,x>0),FALSE)`: finds unique years.
- `COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(x,x>0),FALSE))`: count the number of years.

[image]